# How to fetch DynamoDB records with FilterExpression=Attr.exists via boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have the following code:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr

resource = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = resource.Table(MY_TABLE_NAME)

records = []
pagination = {}

while True:
    response = table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr(attr_name).exists(), **pagination)
    records += response["Items"]
    if response.get("LastEvaluatedKey"):
        pagination = {"ExclusiveStartKey": response["LastEvaluatedKey"]}
    else:
        break
```

When I run it, I get the empty `records` list.

However, the following code works and the list contains all the records with the given attribute:

```
resource = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = resource.Table(MY_TABLE_NAME)

records = []
pagination = {}

while True:
    response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression="attribute_exists(#1)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={"#1": attr_name},
        **pagination
    )
    records += response["Items"]
    if response.get("LastEvaluatedKey"):
        pagination = {"ExclusiveStartKey": response["LastEvaluatedKey"]}
    else:
        break
```

I really like the neat `Attr` syntaxis and want to keep it consistent over the codebase (as in the other places of my code I use this approach). So, maybe I'm doing something wrong with my query?

I'm using boto3 v1.28.44

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good to me, and works as expected in my test. The only thing I can notice is that `attr_name` is not defined, which is something you may have overlooked.